# Lint warning 'Element meta-data is not allowed here' for EnableSafeBrowsing in Metadata

Tags: android, android-manifest, lint

I have added EnableSafeBrowsing in my manifest file. This based on the information provided here: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/whats-new-in-webview-security.html

When I run a Lint analysis on my app, I get the following warning on this Manifest statement: `Element meta-data is not allowed here` (This inspection highlights unallowed XML tags in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<meta-data
        android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
        android:value="true" />
```

At this moment I'm suppressing this warning (`<!--suppress AndroidElementNotAllowed -->`) . Is there any news on whether or when this will be no longer considered as a warning by Lint?

Location in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.xxxxx.xxxxxx">

    <!--suppress AndroidElementNotAllowed -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
        android:value="true" />
```

Comment: Which really depends on *where* it is in the manifest. Add the entire manifest

Comment: I put it in the top, just as displayed in the blog (I will update the question)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add it to the application tag instead. If you read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html), you'll see the list of tags the `meta-data` tag can be contained in:

> ```
> <activity>
> <activity-alias>
> <application>
> <provider>
> <receiver>
> <service>
> ```

meaning it isn't allowed as a child to the `manifest` tag. Put it under the `application` tag instead.

The blog you linked has the wrong info, which also is backed up by the [documentation of Safe Browsing](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/managing-webview.html#safe-browsing) - this particular metadata goes under the application tag

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you have placed all the tag and attributes are in proper Containing parent tag, But could have missed to place: versionCode, versionName and allowBackup in build.gradle file.

**To solve it try this:**

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mypackagename"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Also if there is tag like below in AndroidManifest.xml file

**android:platformBuildVersionCode**

**android:platformBuildVersionName**

remove them (It will be added to manifest by gradle build system), 
It worked for me.